# C++ on singleton

Tags: c++, multithreading, singleton, mutex

I've a singleton class and I'm sure that the first call of the singleton is done by only one thread. I've implemented singleton with lazy initialization.

```
class MySingleton : private boost::noncopyable {
public:

    /** singleton access. */
    static MySingleton & instance()
    {
        static MySingleton myInstance;
        return myInstance;
    }

    void f1();
    void f2();
    void f3();
    void f4();

private:

    MySingleton();

};
```

Now I've another factory class that is responsable to create all singletons in a single thread enviorment.
The singleton can be used from multiple threads and methods are protected from mutex.

First question

Is this approach accetable?

Second question

I've a complex class that must be thread safe. 
 This class has to be a singleton. How can that a calling of different methods of the class is thread safe. For example.

```
{ 
    MySingletonLock lock;
    // Other thread must wait here.
    MySingleton::instance().f1();
    MySingleton::instance().f3();
}
```

How can I get this?

Comment: why do you have a factory that creates singletons? sounds very obfuscated.

Comment: Singleton is never acceptable. Do not use Singleton, it's a terrible, terrible pattern. Also, you've failed to prevent one instance, your class has a public default constructor so anyone can create more instances. Without preventing multiple instances all you have is the GlobalState pattern, which is pure suck. Do yourself a favour and change your design right now.

Comment: True that Jonathan..it's like you have classes and instances, but hey let's also create a global. plus singleton is very UNthread safe!

Comment: Also, define "thread-safe".  Safe in what way? For what usage patterns? Safe against accidental misuse? Safe against determined, malicious idiots?

Comment: The constructor of the class is private and is implemented elsewhere. I've the to use singleton because the class is used in lot's part of the framework. Singleton seems fine for me for this purpose...

Comment: Sorry but I've very lo knowledge about multithreading... I just know one patter: consumer-producer-queue. Is the only patter that I've use for syncroize threads.

Comment: P.S.: I've a "master" class for the initialization of the library. In this place, first that all threads start, I call SINGLETON::insance() to be sure that I've only one instance for the singleton

Comment: Somehow related question: what if I want some object in my application has been created only once and lives during whole application lifetime? What can I use instead of singleton?

Comment: If you had one singleton, that may ne fine, but lots of them is a crock. Also a complex class almost by definition is not thread safe - make is simple.

Comment: Elvis, this sort of defeats the purpose of 'lazy initialization'. @maverik , it's by no means globally accepted that 'singletons are evil'. As an alternative, you could have a namespace with functions, and in the implementation have static global variables (only visible in that translation unit); the functions would be an interface for these variables.

Comment: @maverick - create it once, done.  std::cout is not a singleton.

Comment: My software has very few singletons. They must to be singletons. I don't like much the pattern... but for my purpose is good.

Comment: @elvis.dukaj:  You've admitted that your expertise in multithreading is limited.  I'd like to suggest that you should listen to the advice whose expertise in multithreading is high when they tell you that Singletons cause more problems than they solve.

Comment: Ok... If I cannot use singleton... If I have a class that: has to be used from other classes and has to be unique (because it communicate with a device for example), what Have I to do?

Comment: @elvis.dukaj: Using one class from another is simple stuff.  You already kmnow how to do that.  As far as the uniqueness of the object, my philospophy is a simple one -- if you only need one instance of a class, only create one!  Pass shared (smart) pointers around, or grant access through some kind of broker mechanism.

Comment: Some one suggest to don't use singletons... just hava a global static variable (like std::cout). But what if the constructor of the class can throw? the application can't start and this is unacceptable for my sofware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your second question:

```
class MyProtectedSingleton: public MySingleton
{
public:
   void f1()
   {
       MySingletonLock lock;
            // Other thread must wait here.
       MySingleton::instance().f1();    
   }

  void f2()
  {
      MySingletonLock lock;
        // Other thread must wait here.
      MySingleton::instance().f2();    
  }
};
```

Call f1, f2, etc through wrappers in MyProtectedSingleton.

Comment: This protect only the call of f1()... I want that the call of f1() f2() ... is like to be "atomic"

Comment: You have now f2 protected :D How many function can you have ? And it's almost no cost with the power of inline.

Comment: (minor) You wrote "accetable", but I cannot edit your question for such a small mistake.

Comment: but from the call of f1 and the call of f2 another thread can call f1.

Comment: Note that the lock object used to guard f1, f2, etc should be a member of the singleton class if you are saying 'a thread can't execute f1 while f2 is running'. The less restrictive option would be to have one lock object per function, which can be a static local variable if using c++11 (VS2012 and g++4.7 I think) as the standard now guarantees static locals are fully initialized before they can be used.

Comment: You can make f1, f2, etc `protected` in MySingleton. And the lock can be empty (do nothing) for the single threaded situation.